# Why I can't get the selected value?

Tags: vb.net, combobox, selectedvalue

I have two `ComboBox` for `Employee` & `PayrollName`.
on the first `ComboBox`('PayrollName'), using `SelectedValue` is fine but when it comes to the next `ComboBox` I get this error:

> Conversion from type 'VB$AnonymousType_11(Of Integer,String)' to type 'Integer' is not valid

I have tried to search for the error but no luck, I can't find even one

My code for loading data to my `Employee` `ComboBox`

```
Dim _list = MyContext.Employees.Where(Function(q) q.Status = True).Select(Function(q) New With
                                                   {
                                                   q.EID,
                                                   .Name = q.Lastname & ", " & q.Firstname
                                                   }).ToList
        Dim list = _list.OrderBy(Function(x) x.Name).ToList()
        With cbxEmployee
            .DataSource = list.ToList
            .DisplayMember = "Name"
            .ValueMember = "EID"
        End With
```

My code for getting the `SelectedValue`

```
Dim EmployeeID As Integer = cbxEmployee.SelectedValue
```

Why I can't get the selected value?
Sorry I am not that good in english

Comment: Why do you call `ToList` for the first expression? You could save yourself a bunch of memory by leaving that off.

Answer (score 2):

The first statement in the code includes this lambda expression:

```
Function(q) New With
   {
   q.EID,
   .Name = q.Lastname & ", " & q.Firstname
   }
```

It generates an anonymous type with an Integer field (EID) and a String field (Name). That's the `VB$AnonymousType_11(Of Integer,String)` you see in the error message. These values are assigned to the combobox, and so when you look at the `SelectedValue` for the ComboBox, that's the kind of value you're working with.

So you need to do this:

```
Dim EmployeeID As Integer = cbxEmployee.SelectedValue.EID
```

**EVEN BETTER**

That only works because `Option Strict` is turned off, and *that's very bad*. It leads to all kinds of runtime errors. You should turn Option Strict on. That will seem to raise a bunch of new errors is you code, but every single one is really a little time bomb waiting to go off. This gives you the chance to fix those errors now, before they cause a problem for you users. You'll end up with better, faster code, that's easier to maintain.

In this case, that might mean defining a `Class` for these list objects, which seems like a big deal but it's really only four lines of code:

```
Public Class EmployeeListItem
    Public Property EID As Integer
    Public Property Name As String
End Class
```

Then I would further set the DisplayMember and ValueMember items *before* assigning the DataSource. Combine with other fixes, and you get this:

```
Dim list = MyContext.Employees.
        Where(Function(q) q.Status = True).
        Select(Function(q) New EmployeeListItem With
                {
                    q.EID,
                    .Name = q.Lastname & ", " & q.Firstname
                 }).
        OrderBy(Function(x) x.Name)

With cbxEmployee
    .DisplayMember = "Name"
    .ValueMember = "EID"
    .DataSource = list
End With
```

Notice I never had to call `ToList()`. This reduces memory use, and in some cases can make the code *greatly* more efficient.

Then, when using the value, you want to cast it, like this:

```
Dim EmployeeID As Integer = DirectCast(cbxEmployee.SelectedValue, EmployeeListItem).EID
```

Comment: I have tried to include `EmployeeListItem ` to my expression and I got an error in the `Select` part

Comment: You have to define the class, too.

Comment: I didn't solved my problem with this but because of this I gained some ideas how to solve  and other problems too. Thank you so much for the explanation. I really appreciated it

Answer (score 0):

Try turning Option Strict On. SelectedValue isn't an integer and can't be directly inserted in an integer. In this case, it is returning the object of the AnonymousType that you created. You would need decided .Name or .EID

Comment: I just tried to do your suggestion turning Option Strict On but it didn't work

Comment: @kielou Option Strict On won't fix the problem, it will help you see the errors. You still need to specify that you want the EID.

Comment: Oh. Sorry but how can I specify that I want the EID?

Comment: @kielou how you tried cbxEmployee.SelectedValue.EID ?

Comment: yes and it says `Object variable or With block variable not set`